# Sort a single vertices table

Tags: sorting, lua, lua-table

In a first case I have what I call a "table of tables" containing vertices which is represented like this: `verts = { {x,y}, {x,y}, {x,y} }`

I need it sorted this way and I succeeded:

```
table.sort(verts, function(a,b)
    return a[1] < b[1]
end)
```

But how can I do to sort in the same way a table represented in this form: `verts = { x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, ... }`

Comment: I think you will need to turn the table in the first form somehow, then sort, then turn it back

Comment: either follow Ivo's advice or implement your own sorting function that treats pairs of numbers

Comment: Ivo's solution is already the one I used but it's not really clean in my opinion, if there's no other way I'll try to do as you said @Piglet

Comment: I'd rather copy a table than implement a second sort function. having two different sort functions to achieve the same order looks less clean to me but that's personal preference

Comment: Ivo's solution can be optimized by using a table of indices (and sorting that) rather than working with a table of tables. I'm trying to come up with a metatable-based solution (sorting respects metatables), but I'm not sure if it is possible.